# Breeze BeforeSaveEntity create new entity for foreign key

Tags: breeze

When i'll try to create a new timeSlot i want to add the userId. It save all, but the UserId is a new one and the code also create a new user instead of just set the foreign key.

During the debug user.Id is correct and also timeSlot.User.Id is correct.

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
        {
            // return false if we don’t want the entity saved.
            if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(TimeSlot)
                && entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Added)
            {
                var timeSlot = (TimeSlot)entityInfo.Entity;
                var user = uow.Users.GetById(userId);
                timeSlot.User = user;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish or what the specific problem you are encountering is.

Comment: If `var user = uow.Users.GetById(userId);` fetches User from a different Context than ContextProvider's Context, then assigning it to the new timeSlot will mark it as new in the ContextProvider's Context. If this is the problem, try to attach it first like this `this.Context.Users.Attach(user);`.

Comment: Maybe setting `timeSlot.UserId = userId;` will be easier in your case?